# TabBar with bottom sheet

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making Flutter app i which I want to design bottom sheet with TabBar view as below design.

[image]

I have seen option for bottom sheet in `Scafold()` but onlz tabs are visible. I dont know how to animate it as the above.

My code so far is as below

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static final String id = 'MainScreen';
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController? _tabController;
  bool isNull = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this, initialIndex: 2);
    _tabController!.addListener(_tabChanged);
  }

  void _tabChanged() {
    if (_tabController!.indexIsChanging) {
      print('tabChanged: ${_tabController!.index}');
    }
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController!.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            children: [
              HomePage(),
              PersonalData(),
              LoginPage(),
              RegistrationPage()
            ],
          )
      ),
      bottomSheet: SafeArea(
          child: TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            labelColor: color,
            indicatorColor: Colors.black,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
            tabs: [
              const Tab(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.home_outlined,
                  //color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              const Tab(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
                  //color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              const Tab(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.favorite_border,
                  //color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              const Tab(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.send,
                  //color: Colors.white,
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

AnyOne has some idea how to do it?? If there is some package to use for this bottom sheet behaviour ??

Comment: I guess you could get the result you want if you play around with DraggableScrollableSheet widget .https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hgw819mL_78

Comment: Do you know [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel)? It might help to achieve what you like, but you have to add the animation yourself, perhaps using `panelBuilder`, which is currently in beta.

Comment: @PeterKoltai   Thank you for introducing the package. I have tried the package it was good. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Philip You are welcome, I also use it and have good experiences.